# Contentful - How to add/manage multiple fields from a Contentful App?

Tags: contentful

I want to add 3 custom fields to my content model
By going the field extension route, I would have to create an app for each field that I want and that would mean host each of them separately and configure them individually with my contentful space.

So I was wondering if I can use the contentful app for my use case?

But it seems I can have only 1 field in my app. Is that true?

for eg. If I want to have 3 fields such as
Categories, Sub-categories, Tags as 3 custom fields, If I add them as 3 fields in my Field.tsx of the contentful app, how do I sent value in the sdk for a given field?
eg. this.props.sdk.field.setValue(), how do I select which field to set the value for?